# Selection of words in a N number of sentences using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have address column as follows

```
#23 newyork USA 56778
24567 london UK 
56-67 france germany germany 67886
```

I need to write a regular expression to select pattern of above rows ans I need to replace spaces /s with '+' I tried but I could able to select only one pattern. I need to select any number of words in the rows.

I tried

```
^([a-zA-Z#-])\s*(.+)\s(.+)\s(.+)
```

The above regular expression selecting if the address contains only 4 words if address contains 5 separate words giving wrong result

Comment: Will be helpful if you add the desired outcome from your example and mention what tool you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to replace the space with `\s` also the new lines (`\n`) will be replaced (depending on your language/tool).
=> preferably you use a real space character   to select just a space or `[[:blank:]]` if you want to select non-line-breaking whitespace.

So you search `[[:blank:]]+`.
This will select "one or more subsequent white space" (without `\n`)

To select all ocurences of the pattern you need to set the "global" option, usually the letter `g`. The details depend on your language/tool.

For `sed` this would look like this:

```bash
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/+/g' datafile
```

To limit the lines to the condition *"starts with `#`, `-` or a `letter`"* you have to write this condition. This also depends on your used language/tool.
For `sed` this would be:

```bash
sed -E '/^[a-zA-Z#-]/{ s/[[:blank:]]+/+/g }' datafile
```

The essential point is, that you use the "global" option for your language/tool.

Comment: But that will replace all spaces, and the OP's pattern should start with `^[a-zA-Z#-]`

Comment: In that case, for sed I would go with the second pattern (as the first replaces all spaces, and the third does not replace anything for the given example)

Comment: @Thefourthbird : Thanks, you are right. I didn't check well. It should have been `sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z#-][^[[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]+/\1+/g' filename`, but this only substitutes the first ocurence of the space. — The same problem the question describes. So I deleted the last one as it's not functional and would become to complicated compared to the second one.